# What kind of baptism do the Anglican's practice?

Tags: protestantism, baptism, anglicanism

I came across

> *By April the group was in danger of a split. Taylor admitted his folly
>   in rebaptizing Anglicans and never again swerved from a true
>   interdenominational position.*

in [James Hudson Taylor Biography](https://www.wholesomewords.org/missions/biotaylor2.html)

Any idea if Anglicans took infant baptism and Hudson Taylor stopped rebaptising Anglicans who had taken only infant baptism?

Comment: What do you mean by "if Anglicans took infant baptism"? Anglicans do practice infant baptism, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anglicans are more or less part of the covenant theology tradition, which typically includes infant baptism as the replacement for Jewish circumcision (and often is the state church as well).

By rebaptizing Anglicans, Taylor was essentially claiming that infant baptism was invalid, and therefore churches that follow covenant theology are fundamentally flawed or misunderstand something about soteriology or ecclesiology or both.

Whether he was correct in his beliefs is beside the point. His battle was not to reform the church, but rather to win souls for Christ.  He realized that doctrine, while important, can also be a distraction.  Put another way: Pharisees were doctrinally correct.  Put yet another way: even Satan can quote correct doctrine, if he thinks it can hurt God.